# How to mock httpx.AsyncClient() in Pytest

Tags: python, asynchronous, mocking, pytest, httpx

I need to write test case for a function which use to fetch data from API. In there i used httpx.AsyncClient() as context manager. But i don't understand how to write test case for that function.

```
async def make_dropbox_request(url, payload, dropbox_token):
async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None, follow_redirects=True) as client:
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'authorization': 'Bearer '+ dropbox_token
    }
    # make the api call
    response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    
    if response.status_code not in [200]:
        print('Dropbox Status Code: ' + str(response.status_code))

    if response.status_code in [200, 202, 303]:
        return json.loads(response.text)

    elif response.status_code == 401:
        raise DropboxAuthenticationError()

    elif response.status_code == 429:
        sleep_time = int(response.headers['Retry-After'])
        if sleep_time < 1*60:
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
            raise DropboxMaxRateLimitError()
        raise DropboxMaxDailyRateLimitError()

    raise DropboxHTTPError()
```

I need to write test cases without calling the API. So there for i believe in this case i need to mock **client.post()** but i do not understand how to do that. If anyone can help me to figure this out that would be really helpful for me.

[This image also include my code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otxZU.png)

Answer (score 7):

I also faced with same issue and handled it with `patch` decorator. I share my code, so that might help for others.

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
import httpx
from app.services import your_service


@pytest.mark.anyio
@patch(
    'app.services.your_service.httpx.AsyncClient.post',
    return_value = httpx.Response(200, json={'id': '9ed7dasdasd-08ff-4ae1-8952-37e3a323eb08'})
)
async def test_get_id(mocker):        
    result = await your_service.get_id()
    assert result == '9ed7dasdasd-08ff-4ae1-8952-37e3a323eb08'
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: use `return_value.__aenter__.return_value` to mock the async context.

Assuming you are using [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/) and [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/), your can use the `mocker` fixture to mock `httpx.AsyncClient`.

Since the `post` function is async, you will need to use an `AsyncMock`.
Finally, since you use an async context, you will also need to use `return_value.__aenter__.return_value` to properly mock the returned context. Note for a synchronous context, simply use `__enter__` instead of `__aenter__`.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_AsyncClient(mocker: MockerFixture) -> Mock:
      mocked_AsyncClient = mocker.patch(f"{TESTED_MODULE}.AsyncClient")

      mocked_async_client = Mock()
      response = Response(status_code=200)
      mocked_async_client.post = AsyncMock(return_value=response)
      mocked_AsyncClient.return_value.__aenter__.return_value = mocked_async_client

      return mocked_async_client
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the [RESPX](https://pypi.org/project/respx/) mocking library to test and mock your `HTTPX` clients.
​
​
In your case, something like this should do it:
​
​

```py
async def make_dropbox_request(url, payload, dropbox_token):
    ...
    response = await client.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    ...
    return response.json()
​
​
@respx.mock
async def test_dropbox_endpoint():
    url = "https://dropbox-api/some-endpoint/"
    endpoint = respx.post(url).respond(json={"some": "data"})
    result = await make_dropbox_request(url, ..., ...)
    assert endpoint.called
    assert result == {"some": "data"}
```

​
To be dry and not repeat the mocking in each test, you can set up your own `pytest` fixture, or respx instance, globally that pre-mocks all dropbox api endpoints, and then in each test just alter response/error depending on the scenario for the test, to get full test coverage on `make_dropbox_request`.
​

```py
@pytest.fixture()
async def dropbox_mock():
    async with respx.mock() as dropbox:
        # default endpoints and their responses
        dropbox.post("some-endpoint", name="foo").respond(404)
        dropbox.post("some-other-endpoint", name="bar").respond(404)
        #                                     ^ name routes for access in tests
        yield dropbox
​
​
async def test_some_case(dropbox_mock):
    dropbox_mock["foo"].respond(json={})
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pytest, you can rely on [pytest-httpx](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-httpx/) to mock the Client and/or the AsyncClient from httpx and prevent any request to actually be issued.
Note that, [as stated in the documentation](https://github.com/Colin-b/pytest_httpx#do-not-mock-some-requests), you can still add some exceptions for dedicated hostnames, should you need this.

As you did not specify what you actually want to test, I will let you figure out what you want to check (url, headers, body, ...), but the following sample will ensure the requests are not really reaching the related hosts:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_something_async(httpx_mock):
    await make_dropbox_request(...)
```

Note that you do not need to use an async test case to mock your AsyncClient (in case your actual async call can be triggered in a sync way).

Comment: This was very helpful. httpx_mock is very easy to use! Thanks